# php and pdo skip some record to insert

Tags: php, pdo, row

I am fetching rows from a CSV file but while inserting, some records were skipped. What is the solution for that?

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){

            $total_data++;
             $sql="SELECT id FROM customers WHERE id ='".$line[0]."'";
            $db->query(  $sql);

            $check = $db->resultset();
            $num = $db->rowCount();

            if($num > 0){
                $update_data++;
                //$db->query("UPDATE customers SET name = :name, phone=:phone where id=:id");
                $db->bind(':name', $line[1]);
                $db->bind(':phone', $line[2]);
                $db->bind(':id', $line[0]);
                $db->execute();

            }else{
                   $insert_data++;
                $db->query("INSERT INTO customers(id,name,phone) VALUES (:id,:name,:phone)");
                    $db->bind(':id',$line[0]);
                    $db->bind(':name', $line[1]);
                    $db->bind(':phone', $line[2]);
                    $db->execute();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically with PDO you have to store results of calls to [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), etc. and call the methods on the returned prepared statements...

[query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) returns a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object so save that in a variable, e.g. `$statement`, and then call methods like [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) on that variable:

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){
    $total_data++;
    $sql="SELECT id FROM customers WHERE id ='".$line[0]."'";
    $statement = db->query(  $sql);

    $check = $statement->resultset();
    $num = $statement->rowCount();

    if($num > 0){
        $update_data++;
        $updateStatement = $db->query("UPDATE customers SET name = :name, phone=:phone where id=:id");
        $updateStatement->bind(':name', $line[1]);
        $updateStatement->bind(':phone', $line[2]);
        $updateStatement->bind(':id', $line[0]);
        $updateStatement->execute();

    }else{
        $insert_data++;
        $insertStatement = db->query("INSERT INTO customers(id,name,phone) VALUES (:id,:name,:phone)");
        $insertStatement->bind(':id',$line[0]);
        $insertStatement->bind(':name', $line[1]);
        $insertStatement->bind(':phone', $line[2]);
        $insertStatement->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: can be use condition to check  record is inserted or not if yes then what the way.

Comment: Yes use [rowcount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)- read the description and the example - while that example may be for a DELETE query it will apply to an INSERT query as well

Comment: @yogendra per [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php): "_**PDOStatement::rowCount()** returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object._" So if you look at the code in my answer, after running `$insertStatement->execute();` a call to `$insertStatement->rowCount();` should yield the number of rows affected by the _INSERT_ query